# How to really create n tasks in a SubDAG based on the result of a previous task

Tags: python, airflow

I'm creating a dynamic DAG in Airflow using SubDAGs. The thing I need is that the number of tasks inside the SubDAG is determined by the result of a previous task (the `subtask_ids` variable of the `middle_section` function should be the same variable of the `initial_task` function).

The thing is that I can't access `xcom` inside the subdag function of a `SubDagOperator` because I haven't any context. Also, I can't reach to any DB for reading some value because of the autodiscovery DAG feature of the scheduler: the `middle_section` is executed every few seconds.

How do you guys solve this? Create a dynamic number of tasks inside a SubDAG depending on the result of a previous task?

Here is the code I'm developing:

```
import airflow
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.subdag_operator import SubDagOperator

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
}


def initial_task(**context):
    subtask_ids = [0, 1, 2]
    task_instance = context['ti']
    task_instance.xcom_push(key='depot_ids', value=subtask_ids)


def middle_section_task(subtask_id):
    print(subtask_id)


def middle_section(parent_dag, arg):
    subdag = DAG(dag_id=f'{dag.dag_id}.middle',
                 default_args=args, schedule_interval='@once')

    subtask_ids = ''  # Read from xcom

    for subtask_id in subtask_ids:
        PythonOperator(task_id=f'{dag.dag_id}.middle_section_task_{subtask_id}',
                       python_callable=middle_section_task,
                       op_kwargs={'subtask_id': subtask_id}, dag=subdag)

    return subdag


def end_task(**context):
    print('Finished')


dag = DAG(dag_id='stackoverflow', default_args=args, schedule_interval=None)

initial = PythonOperator(task_id='start_task', python_callable=initial_task,
                         provide_context=True, dag=dag)

middle = SubDagOperator(task_id='middle', subdag=middle_section(dag, args),
                        default_args=args, dag=dag)

end = PythonOperator(task_id='end_task', python_callable=end_task,
                     provide_context=True, dag=dag)

initial >> middle >> end
```

Comment: Can you explain what it is you require a variable number of tasks for?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I couldn't properly solve 100% the problem in an "Airflow way" since I think that the number of airflow tasks and subtasks is defined in the moment of the DAG validation. And at the validation no task is run, therefore there is no way that airflow knows beforehand how many subdag.tasks will be scheduled.

The way I circumvented this issue might not be the best (I'm open to suggestions) but it works:

main_dag.py

```
# imports omitted for brevity
def get_info_from_db():
    # get info from db or somewhere else, this info will define the number of subdag tasks to run
    return urls, names

dag = DAG(...)

urls, names = get_info_from_db()

# You may ignore the dummy operators
start = DummyOperator(task_id='start', default_args=args, dag=dag)
sub_section = SubDagOperator(
    task_id='import-file',
    subdag=imported_subdag(DAG_NAME, 'subdag-name', args, urls=urls, file_names=names),
    default_args=args,
    dag=dag,
)
end = DummyOperator(task_id='end', default_args=args, dag=dag)

start.set_downstream(sub_section)
section_1.set_downstream(end)
```

Then finally I have my subdag.py (Make sure it is discoverable from airflow) in case it is in a separate file

```
# imports omitted for brevity
def fetch_files(file_url, file_name):
    # get file and save it to disk
    return file_location

# this is how I get info returned from the previous task: fetch_files
def validate_file(task_id, **kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    task = 'fetch_file-{}'.format(task_id)
    file_location = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=task)

def imported_subdag(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name, args, urls, file_names):
    dag_subdag = DAG(
        dag_id='%s.%s' % (parent_dag_name, child_dag_name),
        default_args=args,
        schedule_interval="@daily",
    )
    for i in range(len(urls)):
        # the task name should also be dynamic in order not to have duplicates
        validate_file_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='validate_file-{}'.format(i+1),
                                                python_callable=validate_file,
                                                provide_context=True, dag=dag_subdag, op_kwargs={'task_id': i + 1})
        fetch_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='fetch_file-{}'.format(i+1),
                                        python_callable=fetch_zip, dag=dag_subdag,
                                        op_kwargs={'file_url': urls[i], 'file_name': file_names[i]})
        fetch_operator.set_downstream(validate_file_operator)
    return dag_subdag
```

Basically my logic is that in the moment of the validation by Airflow `get_info_from_db()` gets executed and all dags and subdags are properly scheduled dynamically. If I add or remove content from the db, the number of tasks to be run will be updated in the next dag validation.

This approach suited my use case, but I hope in the future Airflow supports this feature (dynamic number of tasks/subdag.tasks) natively.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the nice approach @Hito. I tried something similar, but the thing is that my `get_info_from_db` function is very costly, and shouldn't be executed in the dag validation, only in a real DAG run.

Comment: Of course I understand, that is the clear downside of this approach. Sadly I am not aware of another workaround, if you find out one please let me know.